# Android Studio:An alert box showed when I try to add RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx, android-jetpack

[image]

[image]

Warning text is:

> This operation requires the library androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:+.
>
> Problem: Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found.
>   Version incompatibility between:
>   - androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0@aar and:
>   - androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0@aar
>
> With the dependency:
>   - androidx.annotation:*:1.1.0 versus:
>   - androidx.annotation:*:2.0.0
>
> The project may not compile after adding this library. Would you like
>   to add it anyway

After I chose OK and added the RecyclerView，I still can't use it because when I selected the added RecyclerView it shows No component selected in the Attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your `app.gradle`

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.0'
```

or you can add the Google Material Design Lib using

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

So you can use all Material Components like `CardView, SnackBar, etc`

Hope this will help!